# How to push persistent events from a central server to others?

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, push, persistent

I have a system that consists of one central server, many mobile clients and many worker server. Each worker server has its own database and may be on the customer infrastructure (when he purchases the on premise installation).

In my current design, mobile clients send updates to the central server, which updates its database. The worker servers periodically pull the central to get updated information. This "pull model" creates a lot of requests and is still not suficient, because workers often use outdated information.

I want a "push model", where the central server can "post" updates to "somewhere", which persist the last version of the data. Then workers can "subscribe" to this "somewhere" and be always up-to-date.

The main problems are:

1. A worker server may be offline when an update happen. When it come back online, it should receive the updates it lost.
2. A new worker server may be created and need to get the updated data, even the data that was posted before it exists.

A bonus point:

3. Not needing to manage this "somewhere" myself. My application is deployed at AWS, so if there's any combination of services I can use to achieve that would be great. Everything I found has limited time data retention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems with a **push model** are:

- If clients are offline, the central system would need a retry method, which would generate many more requests than a push model
- The clients might be behind firewalls, so cannot receive the message
- It is not scalable

A **pull model** is much more efficient:

- Clients should retrieve the latest data when the start, and also at regular intervals
- New clients simply connect to the central server -- no need to update the central server with a list of clients (depending upon your security needs)
- It is much more scalable

There are several options for **serving traffic to pull requests**:

- Via an API call, powered by AWS API Gateway. You would then need an AWS Lambda function or a web server to handle the request.
- Directly from DynamoDB (but the clients would require access credentials)
- From an Amazon S3 bucket

Using an S3 bucket has many **advantages**: Highly scalable, a good range of security options (public; via credentials; via pre-signed URLs), no servers required.

Simply put the data in an S3 bucket and have the clients "pull" the data. You could have one set of files for "every" client, and a specific file for each individual client, thereby enabling individual configuration. Just think of S3 as a **very large key-value datastore**.

Comment: I was not thinking about a direct push, but something more like pub/sub with the help of an intermediary. So the central need to send each update only once. The workers would receive updates immediately, but also can receive everything published while they was offline or didn´t exist yet. But then I would need a pub/sub with messages persisted forever or something like that. It looks more scalable to me. What you think?

Comment: This is not a pure pub/sub model because offline clients would need to retrieve the messages different. Amazon SNS, for example, will send messages (and will retry a few times if necessary) but is not sufficient for offline clients. It could push a message into a queue for later retrieval, but the clients would need to poll the queue. So, it's hard to mix "push" and "offline" capability. Pulling/polling is definitely a simpler solution. But, maybe other StackOverflovians have an alternative to offer?

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question in 2016. By that time, I didn't know [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/). Kafka was released by 2011/2012, but AWS provided the managed Kafka cluster service ([MSK](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/)) only by 2018/2019. If I were to do this today, I would certainly use Kafka and MSK.

Kafka provides exactly what I wanted. My central server could publish to a Kafka topic and the worker servers (which are installed on client infrastructure) could subscribe to that topic. Topics in Kafka are persistent, so, if a worker is offline when a message is published, it would receive the message as soon as it comes online again.

So, requirements 1 and 3 of my question are satisfied just by using Kafka and MSK.

Requirement 2 (a new worker needs to get the messages posted before it exists) can be solved just by keeping the message in the topic forever and letting the new worker receive all the message posted since the beginning. But this would not be a good solution. After some months there would be too many messages in this topic.

A better solution to requirement 2 would be to combine the topic with a web service from which the worker could retrieve the latest state of a record (when the worker is created) and from there on receive updates from the topic.